# sas %str or %bquote want to keep the half single quote inside the macro variable

Tags: string, sas, quotes

when using                %STR(amy.goodman@yaho.com;bill.goodman@yaho.com;jack.goodman@yaho.com);
This gives me the result: **amy.goodman@yaho.com;bill.goodman@yaho.com;jack.goodman@yaho.com**
which is what I want. and this is a macro variable called &email. I need this semicolon in between any two emails but no semicolon after the last email
But for someone who has an single quote in her email address like O'Connor,
        %str will automatically match the single quote
using %STR(amy.goodman@yaho.com;bill.goodman@yaho.com;lily.O'Connor@yaho.com) will cause error.
How can I get the result                 **amy.goodman@yaho.com;bill.goodman@yaho.com;lily.O'Connor@yaho.com**
by using %str or any other macro quote function like %bquote or anything else to keep that single quote unmatched?

THE EMAIL LIST IS imported from excel list and I already put% before the single quote in the excel file: lily.O%'Connor@yaho.com
and HOW can I get the the macro variable &email. value inside the %str(), namely:
**amy.goodman@yaho.com;bill.goodman@yaho.com;lily.O%'Connor@yaho.com**
then I can put macro variable into %str()?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the value already in a macro variable, say from a data step via `CALL SYMPUTX()` function call or from PROC SQL via INTO clause, then you can use `%SUPERQ()` macro function to macro quote the value.

```
data _null_;
  call symputx('unquoted',"O'Connor@domain.com");
run;
%put Email list = %superq(unquoted);
```

If the value is already in a macro variable the the `%BQUOTE()` function would also work.

```
%put Email list = %bquote(&unquoted);
```

You could even use the `RESOLVE()` function to call `%SUPERQ()` to get the macro variable redefined with macro quoting immediately after creating it. So if you have a dataset `MYTABLE` with a variable `EMAIL_LIST` you could generate a series of separate macro variables (list1,list2, etc) from the data using code like this.

```
data _null_;
  set mytable ;
  length mvar rc $32 ;
  mvar = cats('list',_n_);
  call symputx(mvar,email_list);
  rc = resolve(catx(' ','%let',mvar,'=%superq(',mvar,');'));
run;
```

The first example data step works since the string literal used double quotes on the outside and thus protected the unbalanced single quote. You could do the same thing in macro code by using the `%QSYSFUNC()` macro function to call the `DEQUOTE()` function.  Note that you would have trouble if the value includes double quote characters.  They would need to be converted to two adjacent double quotes.

```
 %put Email list = %qsysfunc(dequote("O'Connor@domain.com"));
```

Answer (score 0):

With %STR, you need to mark unmatched quotes with a % sign.  So try:

```
%STR(amy.goodman@yaho.com;bill.goodman@yaho.com;lily.O%'Connor@yaho.com)
```

Comment: Hi, this email list is a macro variable. It was a list in the excel and imported in SAS. I added this % before the single quote in the excel and I imported the email list from the excel sheet.

Comment: Please expand your question to show what error you are getting (and what code you are running to get the error).  %STR() should be sufficient to mask a single quote, but depending on how you are using it you may be removing the macro quoting, or quoting at the wrong time.  The simple example `%let emaillist=%STR(amy.goodman@yaho.com; bill.goodman@yaho.com; lily.O%'Connor@yaho.com);` works fine